# How do I use my coffeescript to change the form method to PUT/PATCH?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, coffeescript, forms, http-patch

I'm using Rails 4.2.3.  In my coffee script, I’m manually editing the URL and action of a form to be like so …

```
    # Alter the form submit behavior
    $('#new_my_object').attr("action", "/my_objects/" + id)
    $('#new_my_object').attr("method", "patch")
```

But I submit my form (by clicking on my submit button …)

```
<%= button_to "Save", { :action => "create" }, :method => :post, :class => 'button' %>
```

The request (on both Mac Chrome and Firefox) gets submitted with method = “GET” instead of what I changed it to.  What do I need to do so that I can submit via a PATCH method?  (I need to do this because this is what is required by my update action).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`method` on `<form>` elements can only be `get` or `post`, not `put` or `patch`. See [`<form>` on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form).

Generally, you should restrict yourself to GET and POST requests when working with browsers for this reason, even though it's supported when using XHR.

Comment: If what you are saying is true, then how does Rails submit forms?  In my config/routes.rb file, I ahve defined "resources :my_objects", which implies updates to "/my_objects/:id", require a "PUT/PATCH" method, at least according to the Rails documentation I'm reading.

Comment: @Dave You can specify [`_method=patch`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#how-do-forms-with-patch-put-or-delete-methods-work-questionmark) as a form param on a POST request to get around the restriction.